# Medium-level abstraction atop SQLite that is available on both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, core-data, fmdb

I am programming (as in "questions about programming ...") an iOS app that uses an SQLite database and that should also be ported to Android in the future.

I am considering not using Core Data as high-level abstraction atop SQLite this time around, but to employ one that is also available on Android. My intention is to ease porting. The app's database requirements are relatively simple.

The native SQLite API is such an abstraction. However, may iOS folks recommend medium-level abstractions such as FMDB.

Are there any medium-level abstractions atop of SQLite that can be recommended and are available on both iOS and Android? (FMDB apparently does not fit the bill.)

Answer (score 1):

I will sugest `Realm` (https://realm.io/). It is available for Android and iOS (Swift and Objective-C) and it is much more elegant to work than SQL-Lite.